# Is the map $Z\times Z \to S_3$ a homomorphism?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

So the question I ran into while working through some group theory problems was, is the map $Z\times Z \to S_3$ defined by $ (i,j) \to (12)^i (123)^j $, a homomorphism?

By looking at the problem, I assume that it is not, by the sole fact that $Z \times Z$ is abelian and $S_3$ is not, but I applied the homomorphism property just to be sure. I am unsure if I am applying it right, and if I am, how do I finish.  Any ways to proceed are helpful.

\begin{equation}
\Phi ((i_1,j_1)+(i_2,j_2)) =(1,2)^{i_1 + i_2}(123)^{j_1 + j_2} \\ \Phi(i_1,j_1) \circ \Phi(i_2,j_2)= (1,2)^{i_1}(123)^{j_1} \circ (1,2)^{i_2}(123)^{j_2} = ???
\end{equation}

Comment: Hint: Just look at the case $i=j=1$.

Comment: @celtschk Tried this and ended up with (23)

Comment: I meant for your last two formulas. With your edit, it's now the case $i_1=i_2=j_1=j_2=1$.

Answer (score 2):

If you guess that $\Phi$ is not a homomorphism, you need to find points $(i_1,j_1)$ and $(i_2,j_2)$ in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ such that 
$$
    \Phi((i_1,j_1) + (i_2,j_2)) \neq \Phi(i_1,j_1)\Phi(i_2,j_2)
$$
Keep it super-simple when looking for contradictions.  We know that in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ that $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ commute.  Do their images $\Phi(1,0) = (12)$ and $\Phi(0,1) = (123)$ commute?